# Ladder Chart in R with percentage

Tags: r

I am using [plotrix](http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=plotrix:bumpchart) to generate ladder chart. I want to display correlation percentage on each lines. can anyone please help. many thanks.

This is my code:

```
library(plotrix) 
args <- commandArgs(TRUE) 
pdfname <- args[1] 
datafile <- args[2] 
pdf(pdfname, width=12,height=12) 
eqdata = read.csv(datafile , header = T,sep=",") 
educattn <- as.matrix(eqdata[2:3]) 
rownames(educattn) <- eqdata$ques 
colnames(educattn) <- c('Cummulative','Current') 
p <- bumpchart(educattn,main="Percentile ranking correlation plot",rank=TRUE,col=rainbow(17),mar=c(5,20,5,20)) 
print(p) 
dev.off()
```

this is output[image: ladder chart]

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you have a data set you can post to work with?  Generally it is expected that you provide sample data (and possibly code depending on the problem) and if possible an example of the expected outcome (this aids in clarifying your expectations).

Comment: Sorry, this is my code 

 `library(plotrix)

args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
pdfname <- args[1]
datafile <- args[2]

pdf(pdfname, width=12,height=12)

eqdata = read.csv(datafile , header = T,sep=",")

educattn<-as.matrix(eqdata[2:3])

rownames(educattn)<-eqdata$ques

colnames(educattn)<-c('Cummulative','Current')

p <- bumpchart(educattn,main="Percentile ranking correlation plot",rank=TRUE,col=rainbow(17),mar=c(5,20,5,20))

print(p)
dev.off()`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would stop running this as a script and work with the code in an interactive session with R. Then you can see what the code is doing and tweek different steps. So turn of the commandline argument capture, and the pdf creation and try to work interactively. Untested:

```
library(plotrix) 
## define this appropriately
datafile <- "..."

## header is TRUE and sep is "," by default
eqdata = read.csv(datafile) 
educattn <- as.matrix(eqdata[2:3]) 
rownames(educattn) <- eqdata$ques 
colnames(educattn) <- c('Cummulative','Current') 
p <- bumpchart(educattn,main="Percentile ranking correlation plot",rank=TRUE,col=rainbow(17),mar=c(5,20,5,20)) 
print(p)
```

Comment: i did this interactively first then made changes as i have to use this output in php.

Comment: now i have attaché output and i want to display percentage near text.